# Where does AppleID/iCloud pull your profile picture from?

Tags: ipad, icloud, apple-id

I recently bought an iPad. When I was going through the setup process I used an old Hotmail email of mine to set it up. Then when I was in the settings of the iPad I noticed that my profile picture was a random very old picture of mine. But I have no clue where Apple is pulling it from? I don't have that picture on my Hotmail account or anywhere else for that matter. It's an old picture that I lost a whole back who knows where, maybe Photobucket, MySpace or whatever. I've never had Apple devices before so I've never created a profile. Any clue?

Comment: I believe if you don't have one set in iCloud it will use the one assigned to you in the Contacts App (if you marked your own contact as "you"). Can you check if they are the same?